# Check if an object is NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I hope to check the type of an object, for NSString:

```
[theObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

it works, but for NSInteger

```
[theObject isKindOfClass:[NSInteger class]]
```

will report error

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the NSNumber class:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) { ... }
```

**NSNumber** Inherits from NSValue : NSObject

**NSInteger**
Used to describe an integer.

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

Answer (score 11):

`NSInteger` is not an Objective-C class. It's a typedef for an integral type. As such, an object is never going to be a NSInteger.

What you're looking for is the `NSNumber` class, which is an Objective-C class.

Answer (score 6):

NSInteger is not an object type. It's a foundation data type. Checkout [Foundation Data Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) to see how it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
//checked
+ (BOOL)CGFloatIsCanNSInteger:(CGFloat)floatValue inAccuracy:(NSString*)accuracy {
    NSString *strFloat = [NSString stringWithFormat:accuracy, floatValue];
    NSRange dotRange = [strFloat rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]];
    NSUInteger dotLocation = dotRange.location + 1;
    NSString *subStrFromDot = [strFloat substringFromIndex:dotLocation];
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"123456789"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [subStrFromDot length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [subStrFromDot characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
//checked
```